# React native When should we refetch data?

Tags: react-native

We fetch our data in `componentDidMount` for the first time.

Then after some time, (even days), if the user just quit the app, I find the components are using the data it fetched although server now has more data to give.

What's the common strategy to refetch data for user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your goal and on the data. If that data is updated often, or maybe it makes sense to let the user refresh.
I usually find myself using one of three methods:

1. `react-native-navigation` lets you define what happens on a screen focus:

```js
this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    "willFocus",
    payload => {
        this.fetchData()
    }
)
```

This will trigger every time the user returns (or enters) the screen.

2. `FlatList` with `onRefresh`:

```js
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    onRefresh={() => {
        this.onRefresh()
    }}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
/>
```

3. `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AppState https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

When AppState change from other to `active` state, you could fetch new data.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground! Fetch new data?!');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```